# create_or_find_by use with RoR

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails, ruby, estructuras-de-datos

tengo que crear un "Deudor" que será una empresa, tengo dos modelos "Company" y "Debtor". Me encuentro en mi "show" de company y muestro mis tablas de "Debtor" dentro de la vista, hasta aquí todo bien. Pero al momento de agregar un nuevo deudor debo agregarlo como debtor_company_id y para esto debo utilizar create_or_find_by donde creo una empresa si no existe en mi base de datos o encuentro una existente.

Para agregar este deudor, abro un modal en la misma ventana, con los parámetros solicitados. si ingresa un rut y encuentra una empresa en mi base de datos debe mostrar su nombre en la vista con ajax, sino muestra un input para agregar el nombre.

Llevo 4 días investigando esto, y aun no tengo una solución.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

app/models/debtor.rb

```
class Debtor < ApplicationRecord
  # Associations
  
  belongs_to  :company
  belongs_to  :debtor_company, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'debtor_company_id', optional: true
end
```

app/models/company.rb

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
    has_many    :debtor_company, class_name: 'Debtor', foreign_key: 'debtor_company_id'
    has_many    :debtors
end
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi método create en debtor_controller

app/controllers/debtor_controller.rb

```
class DebtorsController < ApplicationController
   def create
      company = Company.create_or_find_by(rut:params[:rut])
   end
end
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español, por favor edita la pregunta para traducirla.

Comment: como la edito? soy nuevo por acá

Comment: Ya casi quedó, el problema es que toda la pregunta debe estar en español, la dejaste en inglés y agregaste la traducción. :-(

Comment: Listo, pensé que debía estar en ingles

Comment: Bienvenido. He leido tu pregunta, pero es imposible contestarla, porque mezcla varios conceptos y se deja información, como por ejemplo cómo se manifesta el problema.

Empiezas con `create_or_find`, pero luego mencionas una vista Ajax. Una base de datos es independiente de la vista, y por ello la pregunta debería ser sólo sobre una o la otra, o por lo menos dar información de lo que tienes a todos los niveles.

¿Qué tienes en la vista? ¿Llegan los parámetros correctamente al controlador? Una vez clarificado esto, tal vez podemos ver si `crerate_or_find_by` tiene algo que ver.

Comment: Entonces creo que plantie mal la pregunta. La editaré